# Can I avoid having to change NODE_PATH in WebStorm Run/Debug configurations when I switch platform?

Tags: node.js, path, webstorm, separator

I'm working with a Node project in WebStorm that has a number of Run/Debug configurations with a setting for `NODE_PATH` in its environment variables. (I like to run this thing from within WebStorm, because all the configuration is already done for me, and there's a debugger.)

When I'm running on Linux or OS X, it seems `NODE_PATH` is a colon-delimited list of paths. When running on Windows, on the other hand, `NODE_PATH` is a semicolon-delimited list of paths. This means that when I switch platforms, I need to edit the paths.

The paths are otherwise platform-agnostic - they're all relative paths with `/` as the folder separator. So it seems a bit silly that I have to do this.

Is there any simple solution to this?